# Easy question : Flutter mobile app using Grpc web to call grpc API

Tags: flutter, api, dart, grpc, http2

Trying to call an api (written in c# (GRPC)) from my flutter mobile,:

```
 Future<void> login(email, password) async {
final stub = AuthenticationClient(ClientChannel('https://abc.service.domain.com'));

var request = LoginRequest()..email=email
                           ..password=password;
var response = await stub.login(request);
print(response);
```

}

GrpcError (gRPC Error (code: 14, codeName: UNAVAILABLE, message: Error connecting: SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'https://abc.service.domain.com' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7), details: null, rawResponse: null)).

already set/check the internet permission for device, and already have internet.
checked the service is running and live as already in use in another app.

Any Ideas?,

TIA.

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove *https://* in server domain indication. You only need to pass `**abc.service.domain.com**`